# Error in rank() over function?

Tags: rank

I'm doing the Department Highest Salary problem in Leetcode (https://leetcode.com/problems/department-highest-salary/description/). I'm trying to use rank() function in the following way, but it's always giving me error. I wonder what is wrong?

```
Select d.Name as 'Department', e.Name as 'Employee', e.Salary
from (select Name, DepartmentId, Salary,
             rank() over (PARTITION BY DepartmentId order by Salary desc) as srank
      from Employee
      where srank = 1) e
join Department d
on d.Id = e.DepartmentId
```

I know the following code works well。

```
select d.name as 'Department', e.name as 'Employee', Salary
from Employee e
join Department d
on d.Id = e.DepartmentId
where (e.DepartmentId , Salary) in (select DepartmentId, max(Salary)
                                    from Employee
                                    group by DepartmentId)
```

Comment: Can u add the error?

Comment: @Graciano Sure! This is the error: Line 4: SyntaxError: near '(PARTITION BY DepartmentId order by Salary desc) as srank
      from Employee
  '

Comment: which are u using? mysql? if yes: http://kennethxu.blogspot.com/2016/04/analytical-function-in-mysql-rownumber.html